# removing a view from the activity

Tags: android, android-view

In my main activity java code file, I'm adding a new view with this method:

```
public void AddNewView(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayNewView.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This uses a class called DisplayNewView which has this method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TableLayout.LayoutParams tlp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View view;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_display_view, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.myViewLabel);
    tv.setTextSize(40);

    addContentView(view,tlp);

}
```

So this sucessfully adds the view.

But now, in the same xml resource file that this view uses, I have a button that is supposed to remove this view. This button is also in the same DisplayNewView java code file.

It looks like this:

```
public void removeView(View view) {
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)(view.getParent());
    vg.removeView(view);
}
```

But when I click on the button, nothing happens.  I also don't see any errors in the debugger console in Android Studio.

From my web searches, it looks like I'm trying to remove the view in the right way.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me that the 'view' you are referring to is actually an Activity, you might just want to call 'finish' to dismiss 'DisplayNewView'

Comment: Feels like a XY problem [1]. What do you try to achieve? Why do you use an Intent for it?
Else the removeView code should indeed work. Does it get called? Try setting a breakpoint there or simply Log.d().

[1] http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @domenukk I was just trying to modify a tutorial I was working through.  They had a button to add the view but not to delete it.  So I was trying to code a button that would delete the view.

Comment: @WenChao how do I call finish?  What is that a part of?  Thanks

Comment: The button is a subclass of `View` (which makes @Sabriael's Answer below correct). I think you actually do mean Activity instead, just as @WenChao mentioned. Since everything is inside the Activity, simply calling finish() on this should destroy it. However, usually an Activity is only running once, so you might just exit the app. 
Again: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @domenukk I have a parent view.  I want the Add View button to add a view defined via XML and the Remove View button to delete it, revealing the parent view again. Thanks!

Comment: Think of the Activity as a window. An Intent spawns a completely new window. Instead, you might want to use the `LayoutInflater` you already use in your code to inflate a new View and add it to the current View, like `View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_layout);
Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
....
aGroupView.addView(button);`[1].
If you hold on to the view you can later remove it. (?)
[1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906838/android-dynamically-add-element-from-layout-xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recreated your problem and i don't see any errors in presented code. From what i understand you should have something similar to this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button buttonadd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);

        buttonadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AddNewView(view);
            }
        });
    }

    public void AddNewView(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayNewView.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

```
public class DisplayNewView extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TableLayout.LayoutParams tlp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View view;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_display_view, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.myViewLabel);
        tv.setTextSize(40);

        Button buttondelete = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        buttondelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                removeView(view);
            }
        });

        addContentView(view, tlp);

    }

    public void removeView(View view) {
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) (view.getParent());
        vg.removeView(view);
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.stackquest.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_display_new_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.stackquest.DisplayNewView">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myViewLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Clicking on delete button should delete the button view. If you wish to delete all views you can use `vg.removeAllViews();` and as others have mentioned  why create new intent for dynamically manipulating views?

Comment: I tried your code.  When I click the delete button, it removes that button but not the whole view.

Comment: Using removeAllViews removes every view, even the parent.  I just want to remove the child.  Thanks!

Comment: If you wish to delete other view you must only find it by id like so:   `public void removeView(View view) {
        View myView = findViewById(R.id.myViewLabel);
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) (view.getParent());
        vg.removeView(myView);
    }`

Comment: That removes the text view, but what I need is to remove the entire layout of activity_display_new_view, and show the display view again...kind of like a 'back' button in a browser. Forgive me, I am an Android novice

Comment: No problem use `finish();` in removeView function like so `public void removeView(View view) {
        finish();
    }` it will work. But this way you are not only removing created layout but also closing activity. It is much easier and faster to create activities layouts in xml. As above you have two activities and two coresponding to them layouts and you can populating them with use of `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` You don't have to create layouts progamaticaly and inflate them if there is no special reason for that.

Comment: thanks. What is finish(); a part of?  Do I just do something like: view.finish();

Comment: I found where finish belongs.  Thanks for the help! I will mark this answer.