# Adding a resources xml file to the project leads to runtime exception

Tags: android, android-resources

I want to include a resources xml file to my Android application project to hold some string values intended to have a specific purpose, named `categories_names.xml`, copying it into the `res/values` folder, but as soon as I try to run the application it exits throwing an `InflateException`. Strange thing is, this resources file is not even accessed from within the launcher activity. How is it possible? I report the backtrace below.

```
07-13 13:24:21.842: W/dalvikvm(27215): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mikidep.amount/com.mikidep.amount.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at com.mikidep.amount.NumberFragment.onCreateView(NumberFragment.java:36)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:861)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1137)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4717)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at com.mikidep.amount.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    ... 11 more
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    ... 34 more
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=54; index=68
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:64)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:458)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:720)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:124)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:928)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:103)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    ... 37 more
```

**EDIT:** Here's the mentioned layout. I must also say I already tried to delete/replace the element that seemed to be causing the issue, but it would simply apply to another one.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F2F2F2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".NumberActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/displayTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fontFamily="Lato"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#F07B7B"
        android:textSize="70dp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        tools:ignore="SpUsage" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/clear_next_background" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/clearCrossImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/clear_number"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/clear_cross_png" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/nextArrowImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/clearCrossImageView"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/next"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/next_arrow_png" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clearButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/clearCrossImageView"
            android:background="@drawable/clear_next_background"
            android:text="@string/clear_number"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/nextArrowImageView"
            android:background="@drawable/clear_next_background"
            android:text="@string/next"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/number_button"
                android:text="7"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/number_button"
                android:text="8"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/number_button"
                android:text="9"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/number_button"
                android:text="4"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/number_button"
                android:text="5"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/number_button"
                android:text="6"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/number_button"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/number_button"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/number_button"
                android:text="3"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="6" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/delImageButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/number_button"
                android:contentDescription="@string/delete_button_description"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                android:padding="17dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/del_button_png" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button0"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/number_button"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonComma"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/number_button"
                android:text="@string/comma"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonPlusMinus"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/number_button"
                android:text="+/-"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT 2:** I found that putting those string resources together with the others in the res/values/strings.xml file has the same effect, so I guess there is some problem with those resources. I list them below.

```
<string name="category_angles">Angles</string>
<string name="category_area">Area</string>
<string name="category_electricity">Electricity</string>
<string name="category_kitchen">Kitchen</string>
<string name="category_data">Data</string>
<string name="category_energy">Energy</string>
<string name="category_force">Force</string>
<string name="category_frequency">Frequency</string>
<string name="category_illumination">Illumination</string>
<string name="category_luminance">Luminance</string>
<string name="category_lenght">Lenght</string>
<string name="category_mass">Mass</string>
<string name="category_power">Power</string>
<string name="category_pressure">Pressure</string>
<string name="category_temperature">Temperature</string>
<string name="category_time">Time</string>
<string name="category_typography">Typography</string>
<string name="category_torsion">Torsion</string>
<string name="category_currencies">Currencies</string>
<string name="category_speed">Speed</string>
<string name="category_internet_speed">Internet speed</string>
<string name="category_volume">Volume</string>
```

**EDIT 3:** I checked my R.java generated file to be sure it isn't a resources generator issue, but it looks fine. Pasting the strings section below.

```
public static final class string {
    public static final int action_settings=0x7f060017;
    public static final int animations_duration=0x7f060022;
    public static final int app_name=0x7f060016;
    public static final int categories_fragment_name=0x7f060021;
    public static final int category_angles=0x7f060000;
    public static final int category_area=0x7f060001;
    public static final int category_currencies=0x7f060012;
    public static final int category_data=0x7f060004;
    public static final int category_electricity=0x7f060002;
    public static final int category_energy=0x7f060005;
    public static final int category_force=0x7f060006;
    public static final int category_frequency=0x7f060007;
    public static final int category_illumination=0x7f060008;
    public static final int category_internet_speed=0x7f060014;
    public static final int category_kitchen=0x7f060003;
    public static final int category_lenght=0x7f06000a;
    public static final int category_luminance=0x7f060009;
    public static final int category_mass=0x7f06000b;
    public static final int category_power=0x7f06000c;
    public static final int category_pressure=0x7f06000d;
    public static final int category_speed=0x7f060013;
    public static final int category_temperature=0x7f06000e;
    public static final int category_time=0x7f06000f;
    public static final int category_torsion=0x7f060011;
    public static final int category_typography=0x7f060010;
    public static final int category_volume=0x7f060015;
    public static final int clear_number=0x7f060019;
    public static final int comma=0x7f06001d;
    public static final int delete_button_description=0x7f06001b;
    public static final int display_placeholder=0x7f06001c;
    public static final int hello_world=0x7f060020;
    public static final int history=0x7f060023;
    public static final int main_activity_name=0x7f06001e;
    public static final int next=0x7f06001a;
    public static final int number_fragment_name=0x7f060018;
    public static final int title_activity_category_list=0x7f06001f;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look related to the file you've added to res/values. What's in line 53 of the layout you set the content view to in your main activity?

Comment: post the layout you are inflating in onCreateView(NumberFragment.java:36)

Comment: What version of Android has the device where do you test this code?

Comment: Currently only tested on the SDK emulator.

Comment: I just tested it on a Galaxy ACE as well, getting the same result.

Comment: You mentioned that if you put the strings in the "strings.xml", you get same error?  Have you tried removing the strings one by one and see whether is there any particular string that causes the issue?

Comment: Yes and yes I did, and it seems that leaving 8 or more uncommented, no matter which ones, triggers the issue. This makes no sense!

Comment: <resources> </resources> ? where is resources tag in your strings.xml .. and pls rename it to strings.xml

Comment: I omitted the <resources> tag in the question, but it's obviously there: it wouldn't even let me compile if it wasn't. Furthermore, quoting from [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html), _"Because each resource is defined with its own XML element, you can name the file whatever you want and place different resource types in one file."_

Answer (score 2):

A few things you could try (if you haven't already) to see if you make any headway:

1. Using hard-coded strings in the layout instead of loading them from strings.xml.
2. A quick look at the origin of ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

> ```
> 07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=54; index=68
> 07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:64)
> 07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:458)
> 07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:720)
> 07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:124)
> 07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:928)
> 07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
> 07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:103)
> 07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    .. 37 more
> ```

seems to be the TextView init at this [line](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/widget/TextView.java/#928) which relates to setting the font family.

From your layout xml, it seems like you are using a custom font family ("Lato").

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/displayTextView"
    ...
    android:fontFamily="Lato"
    ...
/>
```

Is this supported by your application? Correct me if I'm wrong but from what I last know, the system-supported font families (since API 16) for the default Roboto font were 'sans-serif', 'sans-serif-light', 'sans-serif-condensed' or 'sans-serif-thin'.

The `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

```
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    ... 34 more
```

could 'possibly' be caused when the system is unable to find and [instantiate](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/view/LayoutInflater.java/#587) your custom font through reflection resulting in the subsequent `InflateException`.

So it's probably worth a try to use the default system font first to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: 1. Can't, I need localized strings, but even if I could, I'm not the kind of person that settles for workarounds.
2. Just checked if it has anything to do with the font, came out it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a late response, but I had the same issue, and removing my "android:textAllCaps" styles fixed the issue. I'm not sure why though.. still investigating.

Comment: I'm also having same situation. Have you figured out why it happens?

Comment: I have also had this problem. Removing textAllCaps="true" fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting your bin and gen folders and then refreshing your project.

Comment: I just tried to recreate the whole project to be sure this isn't a consistency problem, getting the same result.

Comment: Whats going on here: com.mikidep.amount.NumberFragment.onCreateView(NumberFragment.java:36) ?

Comment: `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.number_fragment, container, false);`

Comment: Could you post number_fragment.xml

Comment: So the linear-layout is the number_fragment.xml, how is the inflater obtained ?

Comment: There is nothing with what you've posted. It works fine for me, though I had to replace some drawables that I didn't have and some strings.

Comment: Did you try deleting <string name="clear_number"> ... </string> and retyping it ?

Comment: Why should I? I generated them with a script, by the way.

Comment: Because you are having an inflate problem caused by the inability to read <string name="clear_number"> .. when the Button is being inflated. Possibly a character encoding issue, or is there a funny character that the xml parser doesn't like ?.

Comment: I already tried doing so, it resulted in the issue moving to the subsequent layout element, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in retrieving the string values. The clue is here...

> E/AndroidRuntime(27215): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=54; index=68
>   07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:64)
>   07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:458)
>   07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:720)
>   07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:124)
>   07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:928)

It looks like it is trying to retrieve a string value that doesn't exist, or it thinks doesn't exist. Have a look and see if there is anything in the strings file that is possibly causing it to not parse correctly.

From what you have supplied I can't be more specific than that.

Comment: How is it possible, then? The exception is thrown by an activity that doesn't handle at all the values contained in that resources files, and I believe that adding or removing such a file shouldn't affect the existence of another string resource in another well-formed file.
If the exception was thrown when loading the activity that is supposed to use those resources I would probably blame it on the adapter going through them.

Comment: what are the details for the button object that is causing the error? Possibly line 53 in the xml file.

Comment: You can check it yourself, it's the XML above, a Button retrieving a string value from strings.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to inflate a Button? Because [it seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904900/inflate-a-button-using-xml-to-style) that that won't work and it's a probable reason to get an exception. If you are, this is the way:

```
LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.yada_layout, null);
Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.clearButton);
```

Comment: I get every widget I need from the View I inflate at the beginning of onCreateView in the Fragment subclass, by going `view.findViewById(R.id.yadayada)`. Never had troubles before.

Answer (score 1):

It is Showing ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=54; index=68
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:64)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getPooledString(XmlBlock.java:458)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:720)
07-13 13:24:21.872: E/AndroidRuntime(27215):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getString(TypedArray.java:124)
```

Which means that it is caused by over indexing Array rather than its size. so may be you have used the resource index which is higher than your array size. so first do check that and then try to run.

Comment: The point is, I shouldn't be responsible for the indexes connected to the string resources. I certainly wasn't the one typing `68` anywhere in my code, neither should I know the array lenght is 54, or should I?